# Feature Activation with Powershell

Tags: powershell, feature-activation

I am looking for a good example of powershell script for SP2010 with which I could activate my features with prior check if feature has been deployed (some are "web" and some are "site" scoped. Could you please guide me or provide some samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really good explanation is already been given on this blog, so I would suggest you to look at it

[features-with-powershell/](http://www.sharepoint-howto.com/2011/12/29/sharepoint-2010-how-to-activated-and-deactivated-features-with-powershell/)

[Possibly Duplicate Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34695/how-to-activate-feature-using-powershell-script)

**EDIT**

detect if a feature is deployed or not

[detecting-solution-deploying-status](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32390/detecting-solution-deploying-status)

**Edit 2**

Code of checking if a feature is activated or not

```
$featureGuid = "PUT-GUID-HERE"
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$feature = $web.Features[$featureGuid]
if ($feature -eq $null) { "does not activated" } else { "activated" }
does not activated
```

Comment: I had checked that but not  of much help to me. Thanks anyways

Comment: I updated my answer and how is it not helpful, can you be specific ?

Comment: I want to check if feature is deployed before activation.

Comment: I updated my answer again, check out the link that shows yu how to check feature deployment status :)

Comment: thanks for the help.What i meant was I wana check if feature exists in the site but not activated.

Comment: your question says to how to check if a feature is deployed or not, can you ask another question and I will try to give you an example :)

Comment: I updated my answer again, for more information you can look at this question as well

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/powershell-script-to-check-feature-status-enabled-disabled-before-activating

Answer (score 1):

Powershell script to check whether SharePoint 2010 Feature is activated for a particular Sitecollection

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010setup/thread/fa74e065-9fa6-4c8c-8ea7-18899b11d066

SharePoint 2010 Deployment: Powershell Script Feature

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-deployment-powershell.html